# Multi-language support in StyleX

Tags: reactjs

I have made a decision to try [StyleX](https://stylexjs.com) in a new React project. I usualy build styles with [style-components](https://styled-components.com) but I find the simplicity of StyleX to be very attractive.

I have gone through StyleX short documentation and the [Thinking in StyleX](https://stylexjs.com/docs/learn/thinking-in-stylex)
 section a few times. However, I am stuck at two fundamental points:

1. In a multi-language website, how I go about defining different styles like `direction` and `fontFamily` for different languages. Is this a matter of **Theme**, or is it more about defining styles [dynamically](https://stylexjs.com/docs/learn/styling-ui/defining-styles/#dynamic-styles)? Should I create a theme for language and another theme for colors and other design elements and apply both themes as [explained here](https://stylexjs.com/docs/learn/theming/creating-themes/#applying-themes)?
2. When building a components library with StyleX, should every component expect to receive "custom style(s)" and a "theme" as props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS supports LTR and RTL languages using logical style properties. StyleX supports them. TLDR; Don’t use *any* styles with the words “left” or “right” in them. For example, use `marginInlineStart` and `marginInlineEnd`. This will make your styles work correctly for all languages without needing separate styles.

Next, `direction` is actually a CSS property, so you can apply `direction: ‘ltr’` or `direction: ‘rtl’` based on the language that is current active on the page. Of course, you should also set the `lang` attribute.

If you can’t apply styles on your `html` tag directly, using an effect as explained by @damascus is a valid solution.

If you’re trying to change themes per languages, applying multiple themes is the correct solution too.

> When building a components library with StyleX, should every component expect to receive "custom style(s)" and a "theme" as props?

This depends on how strict your designs are. If a component can be customized, it should accept styles. It’s probably not useful to accept a `theme` prop in most cases though, because themes are inherited anyway and can be applied on a container element.

A theme prop only makes sense on large “container” components where you may reasonably want to change the active theme.

Overall, your instincts are correct. Feel free to create a discussion post on the StyleX repo with further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implemented the required language feature:

I created a `Root` component which accepts `lang` and `children` as props:

```
import { ReactNode, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as stylex from '@stylexjs/stylex';
import { fonts } from './tokens.stylex';

const styles = stylex.create({
  arabic: {
    fontFamily: fonts.arabicSans,
  },
  english: {
    fontFamily: fonts.englishSans,
  },
});

interface Props {
  lang: 'en' | 'ar'; // other languages can be set here
  children: ReactNode;
}

const Root = ({ lang = 'en', children }: Props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.lang = lang;
    document.documentElement.dir = lang === 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
    document.documentElement.className = stylex.props(
      lang === 'ar' ? styles.arabic : styles.english,
      styles.base
    ).className!;
  }, [lang]);

  return children;
};

export default Root;
```

In the `App` component, I used the component and passed the current value of `lang` to it.